# Strange noise after replacing brake pads and rotors

Tags: brakes, brake-calipers, lexus, wheel-bearing, lexus-rx

After replacing front brake pads and rotors in car repair store, I started hearing some weird noise when hitting break pedal. It’s very difficult to record that noise so I just tried to reproduce it by myself:

https://imgur.com/a/OKhsTK6

I am not an expert but I think it sounds more like wheel bearing or transmission, and that’s weird because they replaced only brake pads and rotors.

Any ideas what could cause such noise? Is it a temporarily noise because of new brake pads and rotors?

Car: Lexus RX 3500 AWD, 2007